# Script to keep a running tally of a list

Tags: php, sql, list, sum

I've been running a series of games where the winners get a certain number of points at the end of every game. I'm trying to write a script that generates a "leaderboard" - essentially, keeps a running tally of the various players' cumulative scores. I'll explain my problem with an example:

A group of friends (Alice, Brian, Carol...) play a game of basketball every morning and keep track of how many points everyone scores each day. They want to know how many points everyone has scored in total over the whole week.

When they played on Monday morning, here's how many points each player scored:

Alice: 3

Brian: 10

Carol: 5

everyone else: 0

The group of friends played again on Tuesday. Here are the scores:

Alice: 2

David: 3

Emily: 8

everyone else: 0

And their scores from Wednesday's game:

Carol: 6

David: 4

Frank: 2

everyone else: 0

They want to know, at the end of each day, who has scored the most points so far, so they write a script to keep track. With their scores as inputs each day, here's what their script returns:

Monday's desired output:

1. Brian (10)
2. Carol (5)
3. Alice (3)

Tuesday's output:

1. Brian (10)
2. Emily (8)
3. Alice (5)
4. Carol (5)
5. David (3)

And Wednesday's output:

1. Carol (11)
2. Brian (10)
3. Emily (8)
4. David (7)
5. Alice (5)
6. Frank (2)

If I put each day's results into a SQL table, is there a way using SQL or PHP to produce a sorted list of everyone's total score?

Thanks in advance for your help, and if I hear a solution or find one myself, I'll post it here so people can use it in the future.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SQL table is set up like:

```
name    day    score
Alice   M      2
Bob     M      3
Carol   M      1
Alice   T      2
Bob     T      4
David   T      1
etc...
```

Then your SQL code would be

```
SELECT name, SUM(score) FROM table GROUP BY name
```

This, if you couldn't decipher by the code, would give something like:

```
name    score
Alice   4 (or whatever it actually is)
Bob     5 (or whatever...)
etc...
```

(edit: forgot a comma in the SQL statement)

Comment: Thanks John! One last question, is there a way to have the output sorted by total scores? (Like in your example output, having it display Bob 5 before Alice 4.)

Comment: Totally missed that part of your question, sorry. I think the easiest way would be


`SELECT name, SUM(score) AS total_score `
`FROM table `
`GROUP BY name `
`ORDER BY total_score`


The key here is the "ORDER BY" statement

Comment: Alright, I'll implement this tonight, post it on a webpage, and edit a link into the question so people can see the how everything works. Thanks! Edit: I'd upvote you but apparently I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry =/

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE #TempTest
CREATE TABLE #TempTest (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,Name varchar(10)
        ,Points int
        ,MatchDate datetime
        )

INSERT INTO #TempTest (Name,Points,MatchDate)
SELECT 'Alice',3,'1/1/2013'
UNION
SELECT  'Brian',10,'1/1/2013'
UNION
SELECT 'Carol',5,'1/1/2013'
Union
SELECT 'Alice',2,'1/2/2013'
UNION
SELECT  'David',3,'1/2/2013'
UNION
SELECT 'Emily',8,'1/2/2013'
UNION
SELECT 'Carol',6,'1/3/2013'
UNION
SELECT  'David',4,'1/3/2013'
UNION
SELECT 'Frank',2,'1/3/2013'

SELECT * FROM #TempTest

SELECT Name,SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints FROM #TempTest
WHERE MatchDate <='1/1/2013'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC

SELECT Name,SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints FROM #TempTest
WHERE MatchDate <='1/2/2013'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC

SELECT Name,SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints FROM #TempTest
WHERE MatchDate <='1/3/2013'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC
```

You would need to add the sort descending on the points in order to ensure the board displays properly.

Comment: Wouldn't this give every day's results, even on later days? I don't need to know who was in 1st place on Monday if they've already played Wednesday's game. I just want to be able to run the script at the end of the day, and get a total for all the games played up to the present.

Comment: The last three select statements are samples to show what would happen on each day.  The question was how to do it and this was meant to show how.  I would expect that one would substitute the day each day and not run the script as is.  If you leave the date off it would give you the running total